# Why Vite Cli adds type:module to package.json?

Tags: module, node-modules, package.json, es6-modules, vite

`type: module` in package.json makes a lot of incompatibility in my project.
My question is can I remove `type: module` without any side effects?
I use typescript in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove it. They only recommend `type: module` in your package.json [for libraries](https://main.vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode).